# What does Return myVar != null actually mean?

Tags: c#, refactoring, resharper, return-type

Resharper is a great tool, but it sometimes confuses me as to what the suggested code really means. I have this code:

```
private bool DoesUserExists()
{
    var user = De.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Username == CurrentUser.Username);
    return user != null;
}
```

I originally had :

```
if(user == null)
    return false;
else
    return true;
```

But Resharper suggested the top code. However, that looks to me to be saying return user if it is not null. But the method only accepts a bool return and not a class.

**So what does return user != null actually return when it is null and when it is not?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> So what does `return user != null` actually return when it is null and
>   when it is not

It simply evaluates the expression. If `user` is null it returns `false` and if `user` isn't null, it returns `true`.

Think of this as if you were assigning the result of the comparison to a local variable, and only then returning it:

```
bool isNotNull = user != null;
return isNotNull;
```

Or:

```
bool isNull = user == null;
return !isNull;
```

`isNotNull` would be true only iff the `user` variable is not null.

Semantically, it is identical to your `if-else` statement.

Comment: This expression can be very potent in the appropriate context.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure I'm adding any value here, @Yuval's answer is correct and clear, but maybe it helps to see it this way.

You are thinking of parsing the code something like this:

```
(return user) (!= null)
```

That is, you see "return user" and wonder what the rest of the line is doing there.  But `return` doesn't work that way.  It evaluates the rest of the line, and returns that.  It's more like

```
(return) (everything else)
```

or, in the specific case

```
(return) (user != null)
```

Where `return` gets executed last.

It is much like operator precedence, where 3+5*2 must be evaluated as 3+10 instead of 8*2, because `*` has higher precedence (must be evaluated first) than `+`.  `return` has the lowest precedence of all.

If you learn to read and write code with this in mind, you will find yourself appreciating the refactored code.